# b-form-tags doesn't render properly remove button

Tags: vue.js, render

I am using `b-form-tags` in my `template` in this way:

```
<template>
...
<b-form-group label="Keywords" label-for="input-3">
     <b-form-tags
     id="input-3"
     v-model="form.keywords"
     placeholder="Add keyword here">
     </b-form-tags>
</b-form-group>
...
</template>
```

But it is rendered like this below:

[Please click here to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH9ba.png)

Thanks

Comment: Could you create an example on CodeSandbox or another platform ?

Comment: look like css issue. May be your css is not loaded or getting overridden by some other classes in your template

Comment: I ve replicated the issue
https://codesandbox.io/s/b-form-group-render-problem-thiwm

Comment: REMOVE **bootstrap** from dependencies

Comment: It it works in codesandbox, but in local not. Removing bootstrap I lost all css layout.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I was wrong. I was removing bootstrap as import too.